# On-Click Traversing through specific nodes of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, traversal, jquery-traversing

So I have a modal. that when triggered fetches. 1 JSON file.  The JSON has multiple nodes; however, I just want to target the last 4 nodes and omit anything before it.  The name of these nodes are: `post_a, post_b, post_c, post_d.` **They will always be the last 4 nodes in the array.** *That's the best logic I can think of :c*

I'm at the very last interaction of my portfolio and I'm so stumped on how to traverse through just these 4 nodes.  I understand that it will wonkey logic and I'm ok with this. I'm pretty far down the rabbit hole and now and I just want it to work. :(

Sample JSON file:

```
{
  created_at: "2013-07-15T05:58:25Z", 
  id: 21, 
  name: "Skatelocal.ly",
  svg: "<svg> ... </svg>",
  post_a: "This is an awesome post 1", 
  post_b: "This is an awesome post 2", 
  post_c: "this is an awesome post 3", 
  post_d: "this is an awesome post 4"
}
```

---

Here are the triggers as well as JSfiddle of how it should traverse:

### **[JSFIDDLES](http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDp/8/)**

---

```
postInModal = function(data, status) {

  $(".next").on({
    click: function() {
    //jsfiddles has working interaction dont want to cludder  
    $(".modal-main").hide().html(data.post_X).fadeIn()
    }
  });
  return $(".prev").on({
    click: function() {
    //jsfiddles has working interaction dont want to cludder
    $(".modal-main").hide().html(data.post_X).fadeIn()
    }
  });
};
return popProject = function(x) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/works/" + x + ".json",
    success: postInModal
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var keys = [ 'post_a', 'post_b', 'post_c', 'post_d' ];
$.each(keys, function(i, key) {
  var val = yourJsonObject[key];
  // do something with val ..  
});
```

To draw each value one after another:

```
var keys = [ 'post_a', 'post_b', 'post_c', 'post_d' ];
var index = 0;

function getNext() {
  if (index < keys.length) {
    var key = keys[index++];
    var val = yourJsonObject[key];
    return val;
  }
  return null;
}
```

In your click handler try

```
var val = getNext();
if (val != null) {
  // do something with value
} else {
  // we haven gotten everything already
  // do nothing or reset index to start again or whatever
}
```

Comment: .. and you do not need to sort your JSON

Comment: How would I grab just one key at a time on click of next and previous logic: jsfiddle.net/4gfmu

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this logic, traverse through JSON object to find value of **post_*** values, push into array object. Now this array object can be used to iterate when `.next` or `.prev` buttons are clicked

Traversing code is as below

```
       function js_traverse(o) {
            var type = typeof o;
            if (type == "object") {
                for (var key in o) {
                    if (key.indexOf("post_") >= 0)
                        print(o[key]);                        
                }
            } 
        }
```

If you have multiple of objects of type that you have specified in demo code, then you can use dimensional array object or so.

You can also check demo at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/WDrVJ/)

Queries welcomed!

Comment: when I use this it appends all 4 values into .modal-main when I only want it to grab the first index  I've created a jsfiddles with further logic. http://jsfiddle.net/4gfmu/